# Как сделать переход на сайт с поисковой страницы браузера?

Tags: java, android, яндекс-поиск

У меня возникла проблема с реализацией перехода на сайт с поисковой страницы браузера в Android studio. Подробнее: имеется браузер, в котором осуществляется поиск по запросам, например "Авто". Каким образом можно осуществить переход на первый сайт, выданный по запросу на странице поиска именно с самой страницы поиска. Именно так, чтобы можно было зафиксировать, что на этот сайт перешли со страницы поиска yandex.ru, например. Язык: Java. Буду рад любой помощи. Огромное вам спасибо

Comment: что за браузер? может код приложите какой у вас есть?

Comment: Стандартный webView, на котором автоматом открывается ya.ru

Comment: я думаю что можно сделать через js, средствами android такое вряд можно сделать, единственное что вы можете сделать это выгрузить js в процессе инициализации webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я бы попробовал это реализовать навскидку, при условии, что надо именно дать пользователю возможность открывать поисковик в моём приложении и вручную вбивать запрос:

1. Получать адрес страницы запроса пользователя webView.getUrl()
2. Парсером, например, Jsoup получал бы исходный код страницы
3. Парсером же извлекал бы адрес первого сайта в результате поиска
4. Загружал страницу в webview через public void loadUrl (String url, Map additionalHttpHeaders), где в additionalHttpHeaders уже вкладываются необходимые данные о user-agent или, в вашем случае, о "referrer" -> "http://www.yandex.ru"

Способ немного костыльный, но навскидку ничего проще не придумал. Пункты 2 и 3 сам сейчас в одном проекте использую - парсю первый результат в картинках из разных поисковиков. У яндекса, к сожалению, там есть блокировка, которая со временем срабатывает, если часто такое проворачивать на одном устройстве. Но поскольку вы открываете страницу в WebView то эта блокировка будет сниматься вводом капчи пользователя там же, если вдруг возникнет. Либо использовать API яндекса, оно у них вроде тоже есть, но я заморачиваться не стал. У гугла оно вообще платное.